# Vue dynamic component inside directive not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom directive that mount a custom component and add it to the DOM.
It serves to create an overlay over a component when required.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Overlay from '@/components/Overlay.vue';

Vue.directive('loading', {
  bind(el, b, vnode) {
    const ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Overlay);
    const instance = new ComponentClass();
    vnode.context[`_overlayInstance${instance._uid}`] = instance;
    instance.$mount();
    el.style.position = 'relative';
    el.appendChild(instance.$el);
    el.setAttribute('data-overlay', instance._uid);
  },
  update(el, b, vnode) {
    const v = vnode.context.reloading;
    const id = el.getAttribute('data-overlay');
    vnode.context[`_overlayInstance${id}`].show = v;
  },
});
```

The Overlay.vue component is very basic.

```
<template>
  <v-fade-transition>
    <div v-if="show" class="overlay">
      .....
    </div>
  </v-fade-transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'overlay',
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

"reloading" comes from a mixins that's used to manage refreshings, here relevant parts.

```
const callRefresh = (scope, type) => {
  if ('refresh' in scope && typeof scope.refresh === 'function') {
    scope.reloadingState = new Promise(async () => {
      await scope.refresh(type);
      scope.reloadingState = null;
    });
  } else scope.reloadingState = null;
};

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      reloadingState: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (!this.reloadingState) {
      callRefresh(this, 'INIT');
    }
  },
  reloading() {
    return this.reloadingState !== null;
  },
}
```

So when callRefresh inside the mixin is fired and reloading becomes true i can correctly see the overlay appear but when reloading becomes false again the overlay its not hidden unless i add something like `{{ reloading }}` in the template. So seems like changes in `context.show` doesnt trigger any watcher. Is there something related to the Vue reactivity that im missing?

Comment: probably it's not the cause of your issue, but you should avoid using arrow functions on Vue instance properties (in your case the `data` function).

Comment: @fabruex fixed the data function